# return a vector in a column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R, and I'm looking to create a vector based on .SDcols  row by row.

```
library("data.table")
dt = data.table(
                id=1:6,
                A1=sample(100,6),
                A2=sample(100,6),
                A3=sample(100,6),
                B1=sample(100,6),
                B2=sample(100,6),
                B3=sample(100,6)
               )
dt[,x1:=paste(.SD,collapse = ","),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id]
dt[,x2:=strsplit(x1,",")] # x2 vector of characters
```

now, I got x2 with a vector of characters.

however, I expected x2 with a vector of integers.

```
R > dt
   id A1 A2 A3 B1 B2  B3                 x2
1:  1 72 23 76 10 35  14  c(72,23,76,10,35,14)
2:  2 44 28 77 29 20  63  c(44,28,77,29,20,63)
3:  3 18 34 43 77 76 100  c(18,34,43,77,76,100)
4:  4 15 33 50 87 86  86  c(15,33,50,87,86,86)
5:  5 71 71 41 75  8   3  c(71,71,41,75,8,3)
6:  6 11 89 98 42 72  27  c(11,89,98,42,72,27)
```

I tried with several solutions, all failed.

```
dt[,x2:=.(list(.SD)),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id] #x2 is <data.table>

dt[,x2:=.(lapply(.SD,c)),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id]
dt[,x2:=.(c(.SD)), .SDcols=A1:B3,by=id]   #RHS 1 is length 6 (greater than the size (1) of group 1). The last 5 element(s) will be discarded.

dt[,x2:=c(.SD),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id]        # x2 equals A1
dt[,x2:=lapply(.SD,c),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id] # x2 equals A1
dt[,x2:=sapply(.SD,c),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id] # x2 equals A1
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

=====================================================================

edit: thanks Jaap,

```
 dt[, x2 := lapply(strsplit(x1, ","), as.integer)] # it works
```

Still, I wonder any beautiful solution?

=====================================================================

edit2:

new solutions, base function is much more useful than I thought.

```
 dt[,ABC0:=apply(rbind(.SD), 1, list),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id]
 dt[,ABC1:=apply(cbind(.SD), 1, list),.SDcols=A1:B3,by=id]
```

or more simple

```
 dt[,ABC2:=lapply(.SD,rbind),.SDcols=A1:B3]
```

Comment: paste returns characters...

Comment: dt[,x2:=as.integer(strsplit(x1,","))] #error

Comment: `dt[, x2 := lapply(strsplit(x1, ","), as.integer)]`

Comment: thanks @jaap,   it works